# extjs 4.1.3 Ext.override column not getting executed

Tags: javascript, extjs, overriding

trying to overide a function :

```
    Ext.override(Ext.grid.column.Column, {
        prepareData: function(data, rowIdx, record, view, panel) { 
              //more code...
```

but when a grid is loaded to the screen this function isnt getting executed

instead the function that gets executed is its **parent's prepareData function** :

`Ext.grid.header.Container`

Some 1 knows why is this happening ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a problem of inheritance...  The column inherits from the Header.Container class which has this method (so therefore the column class has it too), but this method actually is never called for the Column class.

The reason for this is the way the grid rendering system works in 4.1.x is such that the rendering is done by a whole row at a time (not an individual column).  This means that having the prepareData function work on a single column is just not implemented by the Extjs team (in 4.1.x) and therefore the function is never used at the column level.

I do believe that the rendering system was changed in later versions though to an individual column model, which means that maybe this method was there for future use in 4.1.x versions.

Comment: the reason im trying to override a function in column is to html encode/decode all the colum's text, if i override the parents prepareData function its a big chunk of code and im looking for a more simple solution. any idea ?

Comment: yes but it will work for a specific cloumn, i want it to work on all cloumn's in my site and not only to the cloumns i use the render on.